# Memória dinâmica com ponteiros em c++

Tags: c++, gerenciamento-de-memória, winapi

Olá, eu estou a começar a usar memória dinâmica em c++, mas deparei-me com um problema. Quando eu faço `new CHAR_INFO[3]`, diz

> cannot convert 'CHAR_INFO* {aka _CHAR_INFO*}' to 'int*' in assignment

e ainda dá erro nesta linha de código: `new std::thread(Func)`, dizendo

> cannot convert 'mingw_stdthread::thread*' to 'int*' in assignment

o que esta mensagens de erro significam? Não posso usar threads nem variáveis do tipo CHAR_INFO em apontadores?
**EDIT1:** 
Este é o código completo do que está a dar erro:

```
int *BUFFER = NULL;
BUFFER = new CHAR_INFO[3];
delete []BUFFER;
```

E também este código

```
int *BUFFER = NULL;
BUFFER = new std::thread(Func);
delete []BUFFER;
```

A função é do tipo `void`, sem argumentos.
Se eu colocar este código separado num ficheiro dá-me o mesmo erro.

Comment: Isso são só parte das instruções. Coloque as instruções completas, para se perceber de onde vem o erro

Comment: @Isac Adicionei o código completo à pergunta

Comment: Você está a guardar um array do tipo `CHAR_INFO` num `int*`. Isso naturalmente não está correto, pois são dois tipos diferentes, e por isso dá erro. `int*` tem de guardar inteiros.

Comment: @Isac Obrigado pela sugestão, funcionou, bastou trocar o tipo de dados dos ponteiros. Podia transformar o comentário numa resposta para assim poder marcar como correta?